# Getting error while downgrading angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am running hybrid angular 1 app and angular 2 app. I have created a component **ActivateAccount**. While i am running this application.
I am getting console error while downgrading component. **`Cannot read property 'resolveComponentFactory' of undefined <activate-account class="ng-scope">`**

I do searched related to this error but i found nothing.

I am referring [Using Angular Components from AngularJS Code](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code)

**app.module.js**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { ActivateAccountComponent } from '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/activateaccount.ts';


@NgModule({
  imports:  [ 
                BrowserModule,
                UpgradeModule ,
                HttpModule
            ],

  declarations: [
                 ActivateAccountComponent
                    ],
    entryComponents: [
                    ActivateAccountComponent
                       ]
})

export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

    ngDoBootstrap() {

    var app= angular.module('IdeolveActivateAccount', ['ngMaterial', 'jlareau.bowser', 'validation.match', 'ngDialog', 'ngMessages']);


        app.controller("ActivateAccountApp", loadActivateAccountApp);
        angular.module('IdeolveActivateAccount').directive('activateAccount', downgradeComponent({ component: ActivateAccountComponent }));

        app.component("ideolveformcomponent",{
            bindings:{
                showideolvelink: '<'
            },
            controller: 'ActivateAccountApp',
            templateUrl: '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/login/template/landingdisplay.html'
        });

        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['IdeolveActivateAccount']);
    }
}
```

**activateaccount.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'activate-account',
    template: '<div class="ActivateAccountContainer marginlefttwentypx margintoptwentypx marginrighttwentypx marginbottomtwentypx heighthundredpercent"></div>'     
})

export class ActivateAccountComponent {
    constructor() {}    
}
```

I think i am missing something. I have checked all my code against tutorial given into above link, But i am getting console error.

Comment: Could you add code of your ActivateAccountService?

Comment: @JaroslawK. updated the question.

Comment: why you didn't declare `emailId` and `BASE_URL` in your ActivateAccountService? Try `email: string;` and `BASE_URL: string;`, before constructor

Comment: @JaroslawK. Updated my code. But still getting same error. Anything i am doing wrong to downgrade component ?

Comment: Try add `providers: [Http, ActivateAccountService]` to providers arrays in app.module and delete from `@Component` in ActivateAccountComponent

Comment: @JaroslawK. Updated, but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156361/discussion-between-jaroslaw-k-and-kaustubh-khare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156361/discussion-between-jaroslaw-k-and-kaustubh-khare), the following steps helped:

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    {provide: 'CLIENT_ID', useValue: CLIENT_ID},
    {provide: 'APP_NAME', useValue: APP_NAME},
    {provide: 'AUTH_TOKEN', useValue: AUTH_TOKEN},
    {provide: 'CAN_EDIT', useValue: CAN_EDIT},
    //{provide: Http, useValue: Http}, <-- unneccesary, when import HttpModule
    ActivateAccountService // <-- provide service in module, not component
]
```

**activate-account.service.ts**

Removing *URLSearchParams* from constructor, bacause it is not injectable object. Instead of this, you shoul use `@angular/router` module

Comment: I am getting same error after solving URLSearchParams.